# JQuery Cycle Plugin won't validate (pagerAnchorBuilder)

Tags: jquery, plugins, cycle, validation

I'm using the awesome [jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), with the `pagerAnchorBuilder` to build some pager items, so the user is able to switch between images.

Here's my code.

```
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#slider<?php the_ID(); ?>').cycle({
            fx:     'fade',//scrollDown
            pager:  '#bullets<?php the_ID(); ?>', 
            pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
                return '<a href="#">&</a>'; 
            }
        });
    });
```

All is working pretty good, except by the fact that the `return` part gives me some problems with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)..

> Line 92, Column 31: document type does not allow element "a" here
>
> ```
>               return '<a href="#">&</a>';
> ```
>
> The element named above was found in a context where it is not allowed. This could mean >that you have incorrectly nested elements -- such as a "style" element in the "body" >section instead of inside "head" -- or two elements that overlap (which is not allowed).
>
> One common cause for this error is the use of XHTML syntax in HTML documents. Due to >HTML's rules of implicitly closed elements, this error can create cascading effects. For >instance, using XHTML's "self-closing" tags for "meta" and "link" in the "head" section >of a HTML document may cause the parser to infer the end of the "head" section and the >beginning of the "body" section (where "link" and "meta" are not allowed; hence the >reported error).

My DocType is: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Many thanks if anybody had a clue about why this is happening...

Comment: What element are you inserting the `<a>` into?

Comment: Hi Matt, I'm inserting it in a div: <div id="bullets<?php the_ID(); ?>"></div>

Comment: if I change the doctype to 4.01 Strict, the error message changes to: "end tag for element "A" which is not open", if this clears a bit more the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just thinks that you're trying to insert an anchor element inside the script tag (or .js file), where it's invalid. Just ignore it, and remember that validation isn't everything. Your main goal is to make sure it works.

Edit: If you want to get a perfect validation and maybe even follow some good-practices, you can use the following:

```
return "&lt;a href='#'&gt;&amp;&lta&gt;"
```

It uses html entities. Translated into html, it's `<a href='#'>&<a>`. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) is a simple html entities reference if you want to learn more.

Comment: Hi Zirak, thanks, this is reassuring. Good idea for the HTML entites too, the Validator passes all the code, although now the HTML entities don't seem to work with the cycle plugin, the anchors disappears..

Comment: You put me on the right track: http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#script Because the validator can read closing HTML tags inside a script tag, but not the opening ones, I had to avoid the string to be parsed as HTML, using a backlash \. Final code:  return '<a href="#">&<\/a>'; Validates and works.